# redirect to different url using requested URI

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi i want to redirect every requested URI to another URL with the same URI :)
Like this

```
http://www.fb.com/everything
```

redirects to

```
http://www.facebook.com/everything
```

and

```
http://www.fb.com/anotherthing
```

redirects to

```
http://www.facebook.com/anotherthing
```

I want it dynamically

either using php or htaccess

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#Redirect

Comment: not work i want it dynamically

Comment: Quote: Then any request beginning with URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. **Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.**

Comment: @Quentin i want it like fb.com to facebook.com when you write fb.com it goes to facebook.com and if you write  fb.com/username it will redirect facebook.com/username

Comment: Yes. That is what the bold text means!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a [Redirect directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#Redirect):

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.facebook.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all traffic from that hits your htaccess use the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: mod_rewrite is massively over complicated for this. You need a one line Redirect directive.